# How to upload/publish video from new Google Drive to YouTube

Tags: video, youtube, google-drive

I am struggling to find a way to upload/publish video from the new Google Drive to (Google's) YouTube. I am trying to avoid downloading the file to my local disk and uploading it again—it's already on Google's servers!

There used to be a workaround where you [send the video as an attachment to the "mobile upload" email address](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fnhHyfZhAEc) but the new Drive interface does not offer the option to send a video as attachment any more (at least I did not find it).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

- Go to https://photos.google.com/settings and set "Google Drive / Show Google Drive photos & videos in your Photos library" to "ON";
- Go to https://www.youtube.com/upload and on the right hand side, you should see a option to import videos from Google Drive;
- Click the "import" button, click on your video and choose select.

Comment: Ticking the "Show Drive photos and videos in your photo library" option does not seem required any more with Google Photos.

Comment: I can't see the "Photo & Video" tick the "Show Drive photos and videos in your photo library" option in the settings screen.

Comment: It seems that this button has been removed.

Comment: As of July 11, 2019, this is no longer possible.

Comment: As of April 1, 2020 this doesn't work. There's a workaround though - first upload the video from Drive to Photos. Then in YouTube uploader choose classic version. Here you can see import from Photos option on the right.

Comment: The use of `youtube` api is needed, use: https://gist.github.com/urigoren/fde89fcfa454627152f83e41c3927572

Answer (score -1):

I have tried this tool once before, works ok.

https://imclient.herokuapp.com/youtubeupload/

what do you think?

Comment: Checking the reviews of the app in the Chrome Web Store, several reviews claim the site just downloads the file and reuploads it from your machine, which is not what the question is about. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-uploader-for-drop/bohlpmbngemggkpioibiahganclljlag/reviews

Comment: Actually, it even says it works locally even in the description on the store page. And I'm not too keen on the permissions it requests either; namely access to every file in your Drive, as well as the ability to manage your YouTube videos and playlists, and post comments. This doesn't guarantee something malicious is going on, but it is possible, and there's no reason for it. I'd recommend searching for something else.

Comment: I have now used it several times, it doesn't appear to do anything locally and besides the improper permissions, does as promised. No app store app required I think.

Comment: No longer works :(